# Disk I/O over 100% (~400%)

Tags: linux, raid, io

I'm working with an Ubuntu OS cluster which is using a Job scheduler. Tens of jobs are running in parallel and all jobs read/write in the same disk Array, 3 SSD disks with software RAID 0. I do not totally understand Disk I/O but I see with htop like

```
Disk IO: 394.2% read: 0K write: 80.2M
Disk IO: 397.1% read: 0K write: 100M
```

Not sure, is it normal or should I dicrease the number of jobs running in parallel in the way to decrease I/O ? What could happen if I continue with this very high % ?

Thanks

Comment: it probably mean that there are around 4 process (or rather: 400% of processes) waiting for I/O at the time?

Comment: not sure ... at that moment were running around 40-50 jobs, processes?